# How can I browse to javascript compiled via the coffeescript tag?

Tags: debugging, coffeescript

For development, I'm using coffee-script.js and the coffeescript tag to dynamically compile my coffeescript in the browser.  This works great, except that I can't navigate to the compiled javascript from the browser (this is Chrome and Firefox/Firebug).  If I explicitly add a `debugger` call, or set the browser to breakpoint on an exception, it drops me into the compiled javascript just fine, but that seems to be the only way to get at it.

My current technique is to add

```
setTimeout () -> throw "debug me!"
```

so the code will throw an exception (within a timeout handler, so it doesn't break out of any shared execution stack), which I can choose to breakpoint or not.

If I breakpoint, it drops me into a source tab called `(program)`:

[image: Chrome debug window]

but this isn't any of the `(program)` entries in the list on the left panel, and if I close this tab I have no way of getting back to it.

Is there any other way to get to this compiled code?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert `debugger` in your code, it'll be interpretted as a breakpoint in most browsers.

I use js2coffee.org to get fast preview of my js from coffeescript (just paste it in the coffee to js panel)

Comment: The problem with the `debugger` call is that it gets hit every time -- I also have several Coffeescript files, so that means multiple breakpoints.  By throwing an ignorable exception, I can at least ignore it.  My main headache is that often a problem crops up well after the page has loaded, so I was hoping to avoid reloading and retracing my steps to reproduce it.

Comment: If you have more than one file, it's easier to have your files compiled to js automatically on save, and just reference the js in the html. You'll make your life easier that way ;)

Comment: I'd upvote this comment if I could -- just letting `coffee` watch the source files and automatically merge/compile them made my life easier in all sorts of ways.